# My DropdownButton on Flutter keeps giving me this error

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I am developing a unit converter app as my first project and my dropdownbutton is not working due to this error:

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Centimeter. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 892 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'`
```

I am confused why I am getting this. Here is my code:

```
String? _startMeasure = "";
final List<String> _measures = [
    'centimeter',
    'millimeter',
    'meter',
    'kilometer',
    'inch',
    'foot',
    'yard',
    'miles',
  ];

Container(
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                      //style: inputStyle,
                      hint: Text(
                        "Unit",
                        //style: inputStyle,
                      ),
                      items: _measures.map((String value) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: Text(value),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _startMeasure = value;
                        });
                      },
                      value: _startMeasure,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

I am using 2 dropdownbuttons, here is the other one:

```
Container(
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                      //style: inputStyle,
                      hint: Text(
                        "Unit",
                        //style: inputStyle,
                      ),
                      items: _measures2.map((String value) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: Text(value),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _startMeasure = value;
                        });
                      },
                      value: _startMeasures,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

I am still new to flutter so I am not familiar with the error. The first dropdownbutton I made was working but I needed to reiterate over the items on the widget so the app will be able to perform all the conversions. Here is the first one I made:

````
Container(
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                      dropdownColor: Colors.black,
                      value: sellength,
                      onChanged: (String? selected){
                        sellength = selected;
                        setState((){});
                      },
                      items: Length.map((String value){
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(child: Text('$value',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),value: value,);
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```
````

Comment: can you include more about `_measures`

Comment: here is what I used:'final List<String> _measures = [
    'centimeter',
    'millimeter',
    'meter',
    'kilometer',
    'inch',
    'foot',
    'yard',
    'miles',
  ];
'

Comment: can you provide others two

Comment: for the first one I made I used 
List<String> Length = ['Gram','Kilogram','Ton','Kilometer','Pound']; for the dropdown items
 String? sellength = 'Gram'; for the selected item
then for the second version, I used
final List<String> _measures = [
    'centimeter',
    'millimeter',
    'meter',
    'kilometer',
    'inch',
    'foot',
    'yard',
    'miles',
  ];

  final List<String> _measures2 = [
    'centimeter',
    'millimeter',
    'meter',
    'kilometer',
    'inch',
    'foot',
    'yard',
    'miles',
  ];

Comment: Can you try late String sellength = Length.first;

Answer (score 0):

The error referring you can have duplicate value on dropdownButton.

You can try removing duplicate, most time `.toSet()` works on cases like this[string] .

```dart
 items: _measures.toSet().map(...
```

some do for others list.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work for me

Comment: can you provide it on a gist ?

Comment: got the issue, `String? _startMeasure = "";`  you are providing empty string which isnt available on the items. make you can just juse nullable like , `String? _startMeasure;`